# How to process IRS check as a non-resident?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, non-resident, check

I used to live in the US. I filed in my tax returns, then I had to move out of the country, closed my bank account and everything. Now, my ex-roommate received my IRS check.

I was wondering, how can I process this check? Can I allow my ex roommate to process the check on my behalf? If yes, how? If not, should I ask her to ship it to me? Can I process it outside the US?

Comment: Have you asked your bank if they can process it if you simply deposit it (and the fees and exchange rate they would apply, assuming you do not hold a US dollar account)?

Comment: This sort of thing is the reason why many people decide *not* to close their bank accounts when moving out of the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect @SpehroPefhany is correct and that your bank will cash a check from the US Department of the Treasury.  Especially since they're the same ones who guarantee the U.S. Dollar.  They may hold the funds until the check clears, but I think you'll have good luck going through your bank.  Of course, fees and exchange rate are a factor.

Consider browsing the IRS and US Treasury Department websites for suggestions/FAQs.

I suggest you line up a way to cash it, and make sure there's enough left after fees and exchange rate and postage to get the check that the whole process is worth it, all before you ask it to be shipped to you.

If there's no way to do it through your bank, through a money exchange business (those at the airport come to mind) or through your government (postal bank?), and the check is enough that you're willing to go through some trouble, then you should look into assigning power of attorney for this purpose.  I don't know if it is possible, but it might be worth looking into.

Look for US based banks in your area.